# How to add language to NSSpellChecker's available languages?

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, internationalization

Currently, a call to

```
println(NSSpellChecker.sharedSpellChecker().availableLanguages)
```

prints out this list of languages:

```
[en_GB, en, en_AU, en_CA, en_IN, da, de, es, fr, it, nl, nb, pt_BR, pt_PT, sv, tr, ru]
```

I need to work with 2 more, so I followed [the answer here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/11842) and successfully added these 2 languages to my mac's spell checker. So yes, I have now system wide spell checking in these to aditional languages. And they show in available spell check languages as well as show on following screenshot - first language *Slovenčina* is new (it's code is `sk`):

[image]

Unfortunatelly, `NSSpellChecker` seems to not have registered these new languages as they are not listed as available. List of available languages is unchanged, as shown above.

Is there a way to make `NSSpellChecker` work with these added languages?

Comment: Did you find a solution to the problem? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the `NSSpellChecker` class has some bugs in it. There already was a [discussion](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/215067-nsspellchecker-foundation-broken-for-custom-nsspellserver-servers.html) about a bug with custom `NSSpellChecker` servers back in 2008 (which was fixed few months later).

At the moment I suggest you to file a [bugreport](https://bugreport.apple.com/) since your code is correct as the documentation and the compiler says.

---

**Update**

There are lots of other bugs regarding the `NSSpellChecker` class, so it doesn't surprise me, that you just found another one.

- [Automatic language detection](http://osdir.com/ml/cocoa-dev/2009-10/msg00658.html)
- [Unexpected return value in `countWordsInString:language:`](http://www.openradar.appspot.com/12609104)
- [Crashing application due to `NSSpellCheckerCheckString`](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=5154648)

Buggy `NSSpellChecker` it seems...